# Holomorphic functions from a domain to $\mathbb{C}\smallsetminus [0,1]$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a collection of holomorphic functions $f:U\to \mathbb{C}\smallsetminus [0,1] $, for some domain $U$. Suppose there exists a $z_0\in U$, such that $f(z_0)=g(z_0)$, for all $f,g\in\mathscr{F}$. Prove that every sequence in $\mathscr F$ has a locally uniformly convergent subsequence.

Comment: Should that last word say "subsequence?"

Comment: Are you sure that there exists a *uniformly convergent subsequence*? How about a *locally uniformly convergent subsequence*?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Year. I do not know why $f(z_0)=g(z_0)$ is needed.

Comment: [Not exactly the same](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495848) but very similar. If you don't place any extra assumption you can't expect convergent subsequences: take for example $f_n(z) = n$ (for $n \ge 2$).

Comment: Consider $$\mathscr{G} = \left\lbrace \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{f(z)}} : f\in  \mathscr{F} \right\rbrace,$$ where the used branch of the square root is the principal branch.

Answer (score 0):

The existence of a *locally uniformly* (and not *uniformly*) convergent subsequence is guaranteed by [Montel's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem).

In this exercise, nevertheless, we have stronger assumption: (1) The functions miss a whole interval and (2) They agree on a point.

Comment: How can I dominate the $\{f_n\}$ by a $M>0$ under these two assumptions? Using linear transformation? I have no idea.