# Does there exist $g\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $|g'''(4)| = \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|f'''(4)|$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of all analytic mappings $f$ of $\{z: \text{Re}(z) > 0 \}$ into
itself such that $f(1)=1$. Does there exist $g\in\mathcal{F}$ such that
$$|g'''(4)| = \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|f'''(4)|?$$

We have that $\mathcal{F}$ is normal (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495848/the-family-of-analytic-functions-with-positive-real-part-is-normal)). Do we need to show that $\{f''' : f\in \mathcal{F}\}$ is normal? How would one proceed afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If suffices to know that $\mathcal{F}$ is normal. Choose a sequence $(f_n)$ in $\mathcal{F}$ with
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} |f_n(4)| = \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|f'''(4)| \, .
$$
$(f_n)$ has a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ which is locally uniformly convergent, say $f_{n_k} \to g$.

Now use that locally uniformly convergences of a sequence implies locally uniformly convergences of the derivatives (a consequence of [Cauchy's integral formula for the derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)). Therefore
$$ |g'''(4)| = \lim_{k \to \infty} |f_{n_k}(4)| = \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|f'''(4)| \, .
$$

Finally use that $g$ cannot be constant, and conclude that $g \in \mathcal{F}$.